# Search value in multiple worksheet with Next without For error

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to set up a search box to find value in multiple sheets.

If value can be found, it will show the column in the worksheet. And then click Ok to carry on searching in next worksheet or Cancel to exit the search. I believe this part is working.

However, when value can't be found, I wish it can search through the every worksheet and return with message box "Not found" at the end of search. I can't work out the correct way to do it and it shows error message as "Next without For".

Could you please take a look and correct the "not found" part (after Else) if possible?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Search = TextBox1.Text

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Dim r As Range
        Dim f1 As Range

        If ws.Name = "SELECTOR" Then GoTo nws

        Set r = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 'finds first match


        If Not r Is Nothing Then

            Application.Goto (Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address))
        If MsgBox("found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
           Exit Sub
         End If
            Set f1 = r

            Do While Not r Is Nothing
                Set r = ws.Cells.FindNext(r)

                If f1.Address = r.Address Then GoTo nws
                Application.Goto (Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address))
                If MsgBox("found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
          Exit Sub
          End If
          Loop

        Else
           If MsgBox("not found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        nws:
         Set r1 = Nothing
         Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use consistent indenting of your code you will see that there is a missing `End If`.  That confuses the compiler because it comes across the `Next ws` with no `For` on the appropriate indentation level to match it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Search As String
    Search = TextBox1.Text

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Dim r As Range
        Dim f1 As Range

        If ws.Name = "SELECTOR" Then GoTo nws

        Set r = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Search, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 'finds first match


        If Not r Is Nothing Then

            Application.Goto (Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address))
            If MsgBox("found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Set f1 = r

            Do While Not r Is Nothing
                Set r = ws.Cells.FindNext(r)

                If f1.Address = r.Address Then GoTo nws
                Application.Goto (Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address))
                If MsgBox("found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop

        Else
            If MsgBox("not found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
nws:
            Set r1 = Nothing
        Next ws '<-- This has no matching For, but really you are missing an End If
                '    (Probably meant to be an End If just before your nws label
                '     in order to close your If Not r Is Nothing Then statement)
End Sub
```

---

My "best guess" as to where you want the `End If` (based on the fact that you have a `GoTo nws` prior to the `If` that is missing its `End If`) is just before the `nws:` label, thus making the last part of your code:

```
        Else
            If MsgBox("not found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
nws:
        Set r1 = Nothing
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

Notes:

- You have a `Set r1 = Nothing` statement, but you have never declared or used the variable `r1` anywhere else.
- You twice use a statement of `Application.Goto (Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address))` which is equivalent to `Application.Goto Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address).Value`.  I believe you want to use `Application.Goto Sheets(ws.Name).Range(r.Address)` (i.e. without the brackets), which can be simplified to `Application.GoTo r`.

Comment: Hi YowE3k, I have End If before nws label. Do you mean I need to add another End If? Many thanks

Comment: @JDing The current `End If` is closing the `If MsgBox("not found on " & ws.Name, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then` statement.  You need an extra one to close the `If Not r Is Nothing Then` statement.  If you look down the code as I indented it, you will see that the `If Not r Is Nothing Then`, and an `Else` both start at the same indentation, but no `End If` starts at the same indentation level.

Comment: @JDing I will also put a plug in here for [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project which [one of the other high-rep VBA answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug) manages).  Using it will help you with code indentation, and help prevent these sort of problems.

Comment: Hi YouW3K, it is working now. Thanks for your advice.